# Using Custom Python Memory Allocators

Tags: python, c, memory-management, containers

What I am looking to do is essentially use shared memory for allocations within an existing Python application (technically a Python application running in a container).  Rather than Python ultimately allocating directly from system memory, I would like for any system level allocations (Raw domain) to be taken from pre-allocated shared memory from another a C application that will launch the container.

Note: Host OS is RedHat 7.X

The only way this seems achievable is using Custom Python Memory Allocators as documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/memory.html).  I see how you can create custom allocators for the raw domain but I'm not sure how this would be set up within the Python application exactly.  Can anyone help drive me in the right direction?  Does this approach seem possible with attaching to and using shared memory for Python allocations?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Look into python's `tracemalloc`. It should be a good example to follow for overring python's allocators

Comment: Thanks Carson! I can see that tracemalloc is using the custom allocator feature to override so I'll use that as a guide